# In $\mathbb Z_n$ prove that $\langle h,k\rangle = \langle\gcd(h,k,n)\rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups, gcd-and-lcm

In $\mathbb Z_n$ prove that $$\langle h,k\rangle = \langle\gcd(h,k,n)\rangle$$ where $h,k \in \mathbb Z_n$.

I can prove that in $\mathbb Z$,$$\langle h,k\rangle = \langle\gcd(h,k)\rangle$$ using Bezout's Identity but I need hints for the $\mathbb Z_n$ case.

Relevant: [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2968785/finding-langle-a-1-a-2-a-n-rangle-in-mathbbz-20?noredirect=1&lq=1),[2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2415518/why-in-mathbbz-20-langle-8-14-rangle-0-2-4-ldots-18-langle-2-ra/2415529#2415529)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:
For any ring $R$ and any ideals $I, J\subset R$, one has
$$I\cdot R/J=(I+J)/J,$$
so $\;\langle h,k\rangle\cdot \mathbf Z/n\mathbf Z=\langle h,k,n\rangle/n\mathbf Z $.

Comment: Oh I thought it would be as simple as the $\mathbb Z$ case. Is this the easiest way? I'm not confident with quotient rings yet.

Comment: This depends on what you find ‘easy’. This is certainly the simplest way, since it amounts to examining what is $\langle h,k,n\rangle$ in $\mathbf Z$.